# Flutter barcode_scan error after updating to 3.0.0

Tags: flutter

In my flutter application I updated the barcode_scan package to version 3.0.0 and I get following error:

> E/libc (11783): Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.hal1.packagelist"

The scanner opens fine and once it finds the barcode, the error is thrown. Camera permission is set in manifest. I also found [this issue](https://github.com/mintware-de/flutter_barcode_reader/issues/212) but I don't know how to solve the problem. May be I should move back to previous version? My code looks like this:

```
  Future _scanFromCamera() async {

    var options = ScanOptions(
      autoEnableFlash: true,
      useCamera: -1, // default camera
      android: AndroidOptions(
          useAutoFocus: true,
        ),
    );

    try {
      scanResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan(options: options);
      setState(() {
        print(scanResult.rawContent);
        this.barcode = scanResult.rawContent;
      });
      _showAlert(scanResult.rawContent);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.cameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**
I just discovered that this error appears also in version barcode_scan: 2.0.2, but the scan works fine. So the cause of version 3 might be another.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

- Please update flutter version to a newer version.
- Then follow these instructions: [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to remove android and ios folder from the project an run flutter create . ?